# Sticky position doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Here's my website: www.createpen.com, I'm trying to make **.stickydiv .vc_column-inner** to be sticky, using:

```
    .stickydiv .vc_column-inner {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    }
```

But doesn't seem to work for me. Searched the forums and nothing helped me. I'm probably missing something simple, can you find what it is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use position: fixed;

Comment: In what browser are you testing it? It is still an experimental feature that is not widely supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Chrome. I did the same thing on www.createpen.webflow.com & www.3dpen.co.il, it worked there but doesn't seem to work now

Comment: It do help if you give more context, like html and the css to those elements. You can create a jsfiddle.net if you like or paste the code as a codeblock here.

Comment: use `position: fixed; width: 100%;` on nav should work.

Answer (score 0):

Position sticky isn’t a new thing, but the [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) is now so great that I started to use it, so what’s position sticky?

Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning.  The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.
– Mozilla Foundation

Wauw, isn’t that awesome? No need for JavaScript anymore when you’re building your dynamic fixed headers. So how do I use it:

```
.sticky {
      position: sticky;
      top:0;
}
```

Remember that you need to specify a threshold either top, right, bottom or left. Otherwise, it will be indistinguishable from relative positioning.

**But it doesn’t work**

I had some issues getting it to work on an older site I did some updates on. After some “fun” investigation looking at the DOM I found out that a parent div was having overflow:hidden which means that the browser can’t calculate when the element has to be sticky.
Another gotcha but expected behavior is that once a parent with a sticky child goes out of view, the sticky element will also no longer stick.

Comment: Parent element doesn't have an overflow: hidden attribute, I checked that. Any other ideas?